# How to select separation method in scan module of Kofax?

Tags: ocr, kofax

The following error is received while publishing a batch class in kofax batch manager.

**"The advanced batch class property 'Process documents as independent batches' is selected.  This option requires that the separation method occur in the Scan module."**

I would want the PDF documents being scanned as individual documents than every page as a individual document. But selection of "Process documents as independent batches" leads to the above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each batch in Kofax Capture follows the following hierarchy (note that there are folders which could add additional levels of hierarchy):

- Batch

  - Document

    - Page

A single batch usually has 1..n documents, and each document has 1..n pages. Here's an example for a batch with two documents:

[image]

It is entirely possible for a batch to have no documents, but pages (called loose pages):

[image]

However, you would not be able to export such a batch or process it with most modules.

> The advanced batch class property 'Process documents as independent
>   batches' is selected. This option requires that the separation method
>   occur in the Scan module.
>   This feature will split documents from a single batch into multiple batches. Example given - for my first screenshot: assuming separation was performed during scan, this would create two individual batches, one document each.

However, the key here is document separation, and I think you might be confusing the batch splitting feature with document separation. Document separation makes sure that document are created automatically by Kofax. Imagine you are processing order forms, and each form may have multiple pages. However, there is a barcode on the first page - Kofax can make use of said barcode in order to create documents. There are many different separation methods, and each of them is described in greater detail in the Online Help.

> I would want the PDF documents being scanned as individual documents

I do assume however that you are importing PDF documents in the Scan module manually. There is no way to separate imported (electronic) documents automatically unless they are converted to TIFF (where you could make use of barcodes or other separation methods), so you would need to manually create documents by right-clicking on the imported PDF and then selecting the appropriate entry in the context menu.

When importing electronic documents into Kofax Capture is your requirement, Kofax Import Connector (KIC) is the right tool to use. KIC can be configured to create documents automatically - for file-based import, that's usually one document per imported file.